# Terraform: how to create resources within dynamically-created AWS organization accounts? AKA how to create dynamic provisioners?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Given the following:

```
locals {
    accounts = ...
}
```

where each entry within `local.accounts` variable has two keys (`account-name` and `ou-id`) which correspond with the name of the account and the ID of the Organization ID that the account should belong to, then we create Organization accounts like this:

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "dynamically-created-accounts" {
  for_each  = local.accounts
  name      = each.value["account-name"]
  email     = "email+${each.value["account-name"]}@example.com"
  parent_id = each.value["ou-id"]
}
```

How do I create resources within these dynamically-created accounts? 
 Specifically, I want to create an identical resource in each of the accounts that have just been created.

Documented examples of creating resources in different accounts involve multiple providers, each with a different alias, and referring to these providers when creating the resource, e.g.

```
provider "aws" {
   alias = "accountB"
}

// create resource in accountB
resource "aws_some_resource" "some_resource" {
    provider = "aws.accountB" 
    // ...
}
```

Are dynamic provisioners supported (i.e. one per newly-created account)?  If not, how can I achieve what I'm after?